# In Jurassic Park, do we know which velociraptor is "the big one"?

Tags: jurassic-park

In Jurassic Park (1993), Muldoon has this to say about the velociraptors when he first meets Dr. Grant (emphasis mine):

> They're extremely intelligent, even problem-solving intelligent,
>   especially **the big one**.

The way he describes her it makes her sound like she is the leader of the pack.

When the raptors escape, we only ever see two at a time, and to my eyes they looked to be about the same size. I would have expected that since they made a point of mentioning that one raptor was scarier than the others that she would become a key player in the raptor scenes.  Do we ever actually see "the big one", and if so, do we know which raptor she was?

Comment: [The wikia](http://jurassicpark.wikia.com/wiki/The_Big_One) suggests nothing was different about her with regards to bgger animation, etc, she was merely the alpha

Comment: @Edlothiad Is there any indication in the movie as to which of the three was the alpha? It did not seem like any one of them was calling the shots.

Comment: They say it in the film, that “the big one” killed all but two and took over the pack

Comment: @Edlothiad Yes. My question is if that particular raptor can be picked out in any of the scenes. They make a point in at the beginning of the movie to state that “a big one” killed all the others and took over the pack, and I thought it would be interesting to know if it was possible to identify that one in some manner in the scenes after they escape from their paddocks.

Comment: That's the second part of the comment. And why I didn't answer, there only seems to be speculation if she was in fact "bigger" than the other ones, as otherwise they were all identical (unlike those in Jurassic World) which wouldn't let you tell them apart.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is my opinion that "The Big One" is the raptor that opens the kitchen door.  It's stated by Muldoon that *"When she looks at you, you can see she's working things out.*"  This seems to indicate she's not only the strongest, but also the most intelligent of the raptors bred within Jurassic Park.  For further identification, she calls the second raptor to her and snaps at it when it rises higher than her.  Instead of snapping back, the second raptor shows submission by ducking and hissing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the one that gets locked in the control room is the "Big One" because there are 3 Raptors in the end. One is locked in the freezer and so the one from the  control room had to have gotten out. In the other answers theory, the "Big One" is the one who opens the door. It would make sense with her being the one in charge. She seems to be able to figure things out as if she's watched the humans at her exhibit open doors. The one does snap at the other one when she tries standing taller, which indicates she is in charge/higher in command. 
But the one had opened the kitchen door, and the computer control room door had to have been the one to get out of the other room, knowing how to get out of a shut door. All of this in theory of course.